# accessing specific bits of NSMutableArray components

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

a noob question here.

i have a NSMutableArray defined as

```
lanes = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3] retain];
```

the three components of the NSMutableArray are:

```
<Lane: 0x5544dc0; frame = (201 0; 66 460); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x5544e30> >
<Lane: 0x55450c0; frame = (53 0; 66 460); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x5545100>>
<Lane: 0x5546cb0; frame = (127 0; 66 460); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x5546a10>>
```

how do I get only the 0x5544dc0, 0x55450c0 and 0x5546cb0 bits out of the array and assign them to three different variables for later use ?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Lane *lane1 = [lanes objectAtIndex:0];
Lane *lane2 = [lanes objectAtIndex:1];
Lane *lane3 = [lanes objectAtIndex:2];
```

Don't get confused because of the verbose information you get when you print the content of the array.
Everything behind the address of your objects (0x5544dc0, ...) are just properties of the Lane object.

Comment: I tried NSString *lane0 = [lanes objectAtIndex:0];  but I still get the whole <Lane: 0x5528190; frame = (127 0; 66 460); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x5527ef0>>  in it.    do I need to parse the string in order to get the 0x5528190 out of it ?  I was hoping I'd be able to get just that bit of the NSMutableArray directly

Comment: You asked an array object for one of its objects (which happens to be a "Lane"). You now have to ask *that* (Lane) object for one of *its* objects (which happens to be a CALayer). This is a basic concept in object-oriented programming ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming ).

Answer (score 2):

```
id object = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
```